# How to find  the interior angle of an irregular pentagon or polygon?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have 5 points and measures of sides of pentagon in 2D. Then how do i find interior  angles of pentagon?

Suppose $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5$ are five points of Pentagon $P_1P_2P_3P_4P_5$. I know how to find angle of triangle giving sides using cosine formula.To find angle at $P2$, i have made one triangle $P_1P_2P_3$  and also rest of angles have same process. It is fine. But When i move a point to inside of pentagon the angle at some point will be exterior angle. Exactly i want to find interior angles. Please help me any one.

Comment: You can use dot product to find angles. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: @PrasadG Do you only know the lengths of the sides, or are you given coordinates of the five points? In the latter case see Mathlovers comment

Comment: and if you only know the lengths of the sides, this isn't enough to determine the angles.

Comment: I don't understand "When I move points to form pentagon the angle at some point will be exterior angle." What do you mean?

Comment: I can find angles for convex pentagon but not concave pentagon. I asked for second case. when i move a point to inside of pentagon, the angle at that point will be shown exterior angle. Actually the angle will increase(>180 degrees) when move a point to inside of pentagon. But it's not like that. It will be shown less than 180 degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the points then that's all you need. Use the dot product between two sides, *going in the same direction along both*. So if you want the angle $\angle P_1P_2P_3$, you can do
$$\pi-\arccos(\frac{(P_2-P_1)\cdot(P_3-P_2)}{|P_2-P_1||P_3-P_2|})$$

But this only works for acute angles, as you've seen. So:

---

If you can see which angles are acute and which aren't, just take $2\pi$ minus the above answer for the reflex angles.

---

If you need a computer algorithm: don't store the angles as you go, store the signed $\arccos()$ values directly. These are the *difference* in direction between sides (exterior angles in a convex polygon). Sign them by giving them a third $z$-coordinate of $0$, and computing the cross product $(P_2-P_1)\times (P_3-P_2)$. You'll get one non-zero value along the '$z$' direction. If it's negative, you're turning right. If it's positive, you're turning left. Give the $\arccos()$ values the sign of their corresponding cross-products. Start off by assuming the polygon is on your left. Use this assumption, the above calculation, and the cross product to compute those signed $\arccos()$ values. *Also* keep a running total of the angle you've turned: what we're looking for is something like the [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number). If your total angle traversed at the end is $2\pi$, then your assumption that the polygon was on your left was correct, and your angles are $\pi$ minus the values you stored. If your total angle traversed is $-2\pi$, then your assumption was wrong, and you should take $\pi$ *plus* the values you stored instead.